# Border in the middle first child td

Tags: html, css

How to set border only in the middle (first-child)?

Like this:

1 | 2 | 3

Code:

```
.table {
    width:50%;
}

.table table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.table td{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd)     { background-color:#EFEFEF; }
.table tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#ffffff; }

.table tr:first-child td{
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    text-align:left;
    color:#868686;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

I hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:not()` selector for the first/last `td` with `border-left/right` css property:

```
.table tr:first-child td:not(:last-child) { border-right: 1px solid black}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzcefe45/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, now i got border in middle. But how could I do so its only set on first child? It looks like this now: http://i.imgur.com/Pb80qNW.png